# How to reduce CPU usage in a loop on a PowerPC Macintosh?

Tags: loops, cpu, sleep, exit, powerpc

I’m working on firmware level code that is constantly checking for user input:

```
while (1) {
    if (user_input()) {
        Handle_user_input()
    }
}
```

Currently this loop causes CPU usage to be 100%. What I am hoping for is a way to implement a sleep() function that will cause the CPU to sleep or go into some lower power mode for a specified amount of time to reduce CPU usage to something more pleasant (close to 0%).

```
while (1) {
    if (user_input()) {
        Handle_user_input()
    }
    sleep(ONE_MILLISECOND);
}
```

Please send me your implementation of the sleep() function that you think would work.

Thank you.

P.S. If you wish to use PowerPC assembly language, please use 'asm volatile("your code");'.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what sort of PowerPC chip you're aiming at, but you can look at some open-source firmware and OS code for inspiration.

- you can look at Skiboot code - [`core/cpu.c`](https://github.com/open-power/skiboot/blob/master/core/cpu.c) has functions like `cpu_relax` and cpu idle code that can show you how to do this on modern Power CPUs.
- Linux - [`arch/powerpc/include/asm/processor.h`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/powerpc/include/asm/processor.h) if you're looking at a 64-bit chip, see the `spin_until_cond` macro.

Both demonstrate changing thread priorities. If you want to go further, you can put a CPU to sleep and use a timer interrupt to wake it up again - skiboot has examples.

Comment: So you probably want to look at sleep states and timer interrupts. 

You should check out the processor manual (e.g. https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/reference-manual/MPC7410UM.pdf or similar, section 10.2). `arch/powerpc/platforms/powermac/sleep.S` in the linux kernel provides some very low-level asm and there's a lot of higher-level code written around it.

I don't know what firmware stack you're dealing with or what other utility functions you have access to, but this is a pretty substantial chunk of work.